# HTML5 Video odd behavior in IOS

Tags: ios, html, video

My site's movie plays fine in all browsers but there is odd behavior in IOS (both iPhone and iPad).  (I am unable to test in other devices/mobile systems.)  The video appears with the poster in place. Upon touching the play button, although it takes a moment to respond, it advances to the first frame of the movie and the video stops; however, the audio continues. If you touch the screen and scrub the video forward, it will begin to play as it should.  If you then scrub it back to the beginning, the behavior repeats:  sound, but no video past the first frame until manually scrubbing it forward.

The code:

```
<video controls="controls"       poster="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.jpg" style="width:100%" title="">
<source src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.m4v" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.webm" type="video/webm" />
<source src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
<source src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/h264" />
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf"width="576" height="432" style="position:relative;">
<param name="movie" value="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="flashVars" value="autoplay=false&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.jpg&amp;src=http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.m4v" />
<embed src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/flashfox.swf" width="576" height="432" style="position:relative;"  flashVars="autoplay=false&amp;controls=true&amp;fullScreenEnabled=true&amp;posterOnEnd=true&amp;loop=false&amp;poster=http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.jpg&amp;src=http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.m4v" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_en" />
<img alt="" src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.jpg" style="position:absolute;left:0;" width="100%" title="Video playback is not supported by your browser" />
</object>
</video>
```

Before closing body tag:

```
<script src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/html5ext.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I double-checked the .mp4 file with 2 different converters before posting and it is correctly converted to h264.  In my code, I do have the type for .m4v set to .mp4.  If I change it, there is no play button and the video does not play at all.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: .mp4 file with H.264 + AAC (or MP3). H.264 ?

Comment: try only with this:
<source src="http://example.com/theater/movies/current/eh5v.files/html5video/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />

Comment: BigBuckBunny.mp4 with type video/mp4

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't change anything.  Of course, I'm in the process of reuploading the file; if that might affect things.  Currently, the behavior has remained consistent, with video appearing after scrubbing.  That is the strangest part; why should the video play after scrubbing the scroll bar?  When the file finishes, I'll try again, with your edit.

Comment: I'm so sorry but, even with re-uploading the 1+GB file, using your edit, and clearing Safari's cache on the iPad, the behavior is the same.  I won't keep you further, tonight; you've been a great support.  I'll check back in the morning, in case something occurs to you.  Thank you again.

Comment: Although it's still odd on my iPad, toto, it's playing on my iPhone this morning,  I consider that a victory!  I'll keep chipping away at the iPad issue but I'm happy with the outcome, this morning.  Thank you for your great patience and support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I listened a while, that stopped MAC support for new versions of FLASH ago. mimeType: application / x-shockwave-flash
Then I leave some support lines to verify the mimeType, the version of the mimetype and for all audio and video CODEC that supports the browser.

```
    var util = {
    regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters: function (a) {
        return  a.toString().replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    },
    trim: function (a) {
        return a.toString().replace(/^\s+/, '').replace(/\s+$/, '');
    },
    replaceAll: function (source, search, replace, ignoreCase) {
        var search1 = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
        var result = source.replace(new RegExp(search1, ignore), replace);
        return result;
    },
    isEqualString: function (str1, str2, ignoreCase) {
        str1 = str1.toString();
        str2 = str2.toString();
        var search = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(str1);
        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
        var reg = new RegExp("^" + search + "$", ignore);
        return reg.test(str2);
    },
    contain: function (source, search, ignoreCase) {
        search = this.regExpEscapeSpecialCharacters(search);
        var ignore = (ignoreCase) ? "gi" : "g";
        var reg = new RegExp(search, ignore);
        return reg.test(source);
    },
    isUndefinedOrNull: function (a) {
        return (typeof (a) === "undefined") || (a === null);
    },
    getMimeTypeVersion: function (name) {

        var obj = this.getMimeType(name);

        if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(obj)) {
            if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(obj["version"])) {
                return obj["version"];
            } else {

                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(obj["description"])) {
                    var d = obj["description"];

                    return this.trim(this.replaceAll(d, name, "", true));

                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    },
    getMimeType: function (type) {

        var obj = null;
        for (var o in navigator.mimeTypes) {

            if (navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]) {
                var mime = navigator.mimeTypes[o];

                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime) && (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime["type"]))) {
                    if (this.isEqualString(mime["type"], type, true)) {
                        obj = mime["enabledPlugin"];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }
        return obj;
    },
    getMimeTypeBySuffix: function (suffix) {
        var obj = null;
        for (var o in navigator.mimeTypes) {
            if (navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]) {
                var mime = navigator.mimeTypes[o];
                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime["suffixes"])) {
                    if (this.isEqualString(mime["suffixes"], suffix, true)) {
                        obj = mime["enabledPlugin"];
                        break;

                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return obj;
    },
    getMimeTypeByName: function (name) {
        var obj = null;
        for (var o in navigator.mimeTypes) {
            if (navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]) {
                var mime = navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]; //["enabledPlugin"]
                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime["name"])) {
                    if (this.isEqualString(mime["name"], name, true)) {
                        obj = mime;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    },
    getAllVideoCodecs: function () {
        var obj = new Array();
        var vid = document.createElement('video');
        for (var o in navigator.mimeTypes) {
            if (navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]) {
                var mime = navigator.mimeTypes[o];
                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime) && (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime["type"]))) {
                    if (this.contain(mime["type"], "video/", true)) {
                        var type = mime["type"];

                        if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(vid) && ("canPlayType" in vid) && (vid.canPlayType(type) !== "")) {
                            obj.push(type);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    },
    getAllAudioCodecs: function () {
        var obj = new Array();
        var vid = document.createElement('video');
        for (var o in navigator.mimeTypes) {

            if (navigator.mimeTypes[o]["enabledPlugin"]) {
                var mime = navigator.mimeTypes[o];
                if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime) && (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(mime["type"]))) {
                    if (this.contain(mime["type"], "audio/", true)) {
                        var type = mime["type"];

                        if (!this.isUndefinedOrNull(vid) && ("canPlayType" in vid) && (vid.canPlayType(type) !== "")) {
                            obj.push(type);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return obj;
    }
};

try {


//Check mimetype and CODES.
    var mime = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
    var objMimeType = util.getMimeType(mime);
    if (objMimeType !== null) {
        //Supported....
        document.write("MIMETYPE SUPPORTED<br />");
        var version = util.getMimeTypeVersion(mime);
        if (version !== null) {
            //COMPARE HERE YOUR VERSION.
            document.write("VERSION MIMETYPE:  " + version + "<br />");

            document.write("######## VIDEO CODEC SUPPORTED #######" + "<br />");

            //ARRAY OF ALL VIDEOCODEC SUPPORTED IN BROWSER.
            var arrayVideoCodec = util.getAllVideoCodecs();
            if (arrayVideoCodec.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayVideoCodec.length; i++) {
                    var videoCodec = arrayVideoCodec[i];
                    //######3Print here the result.
                    document.write(videoCodec + "<br />");
                }
            }
            //ARRAY OF ALL AUDIOOCODEC SUPPORTED IN BROWSER.

            document.write("<br /><br />######## AUDIO CODEC SUPPORTED #######" + "<br />");
            var arrayAudioCodec = util.getAllAudioCodecs();
            if (arrayAudioCodec.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayAudioCodec.length; i++) {
                    var audioCodec = arrayAudioCodec[i];
                    //######3Print here the result.
                    document.write(audioCodec + "<br />");
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        //NO MIME TYPE.
        document.write("NO MIMETYPE SUPPORTED");
    }

} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I wasn't sure how to proceed, but I pasted the contents of this JS file into my file editor, named it and uploaded it to my server, then called for it in my file but there is no change.  Was that the correct procedure?

Comment: I updated the JS.
Include the JS in HTML FILE.
Try access the web with an IPHONE or IPAD.
And share the result.

Comment: I included the JS into my HTML within script tags.  I viewed it on my iPad.  There is no change, but I'm seeing this message onscreen:  No Mimetype Supported.  On my laptop, Chrome, I'm seeing this:  MIMETYPE SUPPORTED
VERSION MIMETYPE: Shockwave Flash 22.0 r0
######## VIDEO CODEC SUPPORTED #######


######## AUDIO CODEC SUPPORTED #######

Comment: So, IPAD not is supporting the object mimetype: "application/x-shockwave-flash" > including in the video object : <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>

Comment: I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.  It's not my code, then, that's at fault, or my formats, but something within IOS?

Comment: I would just like to add, please, that tech support for my dedicated server has just informed me that all appropriate MIME types are already in place.  Rather than try to access the video through the web page designed for it, I just accessed it on my iPad via the mp4 file's direct link.  When doing so, the video plays, but the audio is gone.  Obviously this must be code-related?

Comment: you tried .mp4 file with H.264 + AAC (or MP3). H.264 ?

Comment: Yes, I've used (now) three separate converters to be sure that it's correct.  I'll try reuploading (the very large file) to ensure that it was not corrupted during the file transfer.  Thank you and I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: You tried play video without adding the object flash?

Comment: When I remove it, the play button disappears and the video doesn't respond to touch.  The reupload is over 1 GB, but I've checked that the ftp setting is not ASCII, but BINARY.  Auto-setting hasn't always defaulted correctly in the past.

Comment: I can test from my side, but i need valid URL videos.

Comment: can you try  BigBuckBunny.mp4 with type="video/mp4" ?